# Laravel not able to load other URLs other than home(/)?

Tags: php, routes, laravel, http-status-code-404

I installed laravel and getting home page on `localhost/laravel/public`. 
But unable to do simple routing.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('authors',function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Here i am calling the same view on `localhost/laravel/public/authors`.
But i am getting 404.

I have a different view that also with `/` but not with `authors`

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('authors');
});

Route::get('authors',function()
{
    return View::make('authors');
});
```

Now i am getting authors view on `/` but not with `authors`.

Thanks

Comment: Is Apache installed? ... with the `mod_rewrite` directive enabled?

Comment: See if `localhost/laravel/public/index.php/authors` works.

Comment: it works `localhost/laravel/public/index.php/authors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to access `/laravel/public/index.php/authors`, then you'll need to adda `RewriteBase` to your `.htaccess` file, that is, assuming you're running Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /laravel/public
<other rules go here>
```

Comment: Still not working... .htaccess file after adding the two lines `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /laravel/public
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>`